# Explaining the result of pipeline execution of multiple hincrby commands in redis

Tags: redis

This rudimentary one has me stumped. I've been tinkering around with [redis-py](https://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), trying to learn the ropes. One thing I'm trying is:

```
pipeline1 = my_server.pipeline()
for hash_obj in hash_objs:
    num = pipeline1.hincrby(hash_obj,"num",amount=-1)
result1 = pipeline1.execute()
print result1
>>> [0L,0L]
```

There were two redis hashes in the list `hash_objs`. What I see printed on the screen is `[0L,0L]`. Can someone help me decipher what this output means? What's `L`? I was hoping to get the resulting `int` values of `num` for each `hash_obj` (e.g. `[2,0]`).

My objective is to decrement `num` in each `hash_obj` by `1`, and wherever `num` ends up as `0`, delete the `hash_obj`.

I'm trying to accomplish that in two separate pipelines; the code above is the attempting to decrement all `num` values in all `hash_objs`. After this, I would delete the relevant `hash_objs` if warranted. I'm still developing my understanding of how to effectively use pipelining in redis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the code above - the `L` means long (integer) and the result printout is consistent assuming that the hashes were set to 1 before the run. If you set the hashes beforehand to 3 and 1 (steps 3 and 4 below), respectively, you'll get the expected result in step 9:

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: r = redis.StrictRedis()

In [3]: r.hset('h1', 'num', 3)
Out[3]: 1L

In [4]: r.hset('h2', 'num', 1)
Out[4]: 1L

In [5]: hashes = ['h1', 'h2']

In [6]: p = r.pipeline()

In [7]: for h in hashes:
   ...:     p.hincrby(h, 'num', -1)
   ...:     

In [8]: res = p.execute()

In [9]: res
Out[9]: [2L, 0L]
```

Note: the `1L` in 3 and 4 means that the key was created.

Now you can iterate on the result and continue the processing. In your case, however, it would make more sense to use just one pipeline and instead of executing the `hincrby` call a Lua script decrements and deletes the key if the result is 0, such as the one below (which returns 1 if the key was deleted):

```
In [1]: import redis

In [2]: r = redis.StrictRedis()

In [3]: r.hset('h1', 'num', 3)
Out[3]: 0L

In [4]: r.hset('h2', 'num', 1)
Out[4]: 0L

In [5]: s = r.script_load('if redis.call("HINCRBY", KEYS[1], ARGV[1], ARGV[2]) <= 0 then redis.call("DEL", KEYS[1]) return 1 end return 0')

In [6]: p = r.pipeline()

In [7]: for h in ['h1', 'h2']:
   ...:     p.evalsha(s, 1, h, 'num', -1)
   ...:    

In [8]: p.execute()
Out[8]: [0L, 1L]
```